# Sprache - combination of parsers

Tags: c#, parsing, sprache

Using Sprache I have parsers, A,B,C,D which matches with different input parts, and selects (returns) different class instances. In my input there are a lot of parts in a random order, eq. "abaabccbdbabddba". I need to select all 'a'-s and 'b'-s and so on - order is irrelevant:

```
  from a_list in A.Many()
  from b_list in B.Many()
  from c_list in C.Many()
  from d_list in D.Many()
```

won't work this way. How can I describe this situation (best way) in Sprache?

Comment: have you tried using `Parser<T> Or<T>(this Parser<T> first, Parser<T> second)`

Comment: The following

 Parser<Object> Elements = A.Or<Object>(B).Or<Object>(C);

then

 from elements in Elements.Many()
 select new Items( elements.OfType<A>(), elements.OfType<B>(), ...)

and seems to work!! Thanks! :)

Comment: No :( It doesn't. For some reason it finds only the first instances of A and B, not all instances. Probably the parse stops too early for some reason ...

Comment: most likely you missed a `.Many()` somewhere - can you please add the comment to your question (it's really almost unreadable) - also a simple runable example would be great (just give a piece of code we can compile/run that will demonstrate your problem) - right now we see nothing of your actual definitions

Comment: Yeah, it works. I found the bug in my language description. Thank you for your supports! :)

Answer (score 0):

Old questions since 6 years with no answer.
The next code may help someone:

```cs
  var segment=
                from start in Parse.Letter.Once()
                let a =start.First()
                from rest in Parse.Chars(a).Many()
                select start.Concat(rest);            
            var allSegments = segment.Many();
        
        //test
            var text = "abaabccbdbabddba";         
            var result=allSegments.Parse(text);
```

output:

```
aa
cc
dd
```

[Try it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EjeT1S)